# Connecting one Raspberry Pi after another using for loop through ssh

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, ssh, raspberry-pi

Am trying to connect to one Raspberry pi after another but the ssh breaks out of for loop:

```
for i in 4 8;
do
ssh -tt pi@192.168.1.$i "python3 ./replace.py"  && exit
done
```

It connects with the 4 and executes but after the connection is closed it doe not get conncted to the next Rpi, it doesn't go through the for loop it exits.Please let me know where I am wrong.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are calling exit in your current shell and not on remote machine. There is  no need to use `&& exit` in your case, simple

```sh
for i in 4 8;
do
ssh -tt pi@192.168.1.$i "python3 ./replace.py"
done
```

Will work.

If you absolutely have to manually exit for some reason - it should be places inside quotes, like this:

```sh
for i in 4 8;
do
ssh -tt pi@192.168.1.$i "python3 ./replace.py && exit"
done
```

Also, if you want to use this script on all your Pi's simultaneously, instead of going sequentially, consider using `pssh`

```
pssh -H "$(for i in 4 8; do echo 192.168.1.$i; done)" -i "python3 ./replace.py"
```

or simply pass your hosts to -H switch. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh